# show a div content with nyroModal

Tags: jquery

I'm using [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) jquery plugin.
But I've a simple question:
I have a hidden div, its id is `mydiv` (and style is `display: none;`).
If user clicks on the another div with id `button`, `mydiv` should shows in a modal box.

How?

(the body code is:)

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">
    abcdabcd
</div>
<div id="button">
    Click!
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you checked out the demo section... it gives you all the code you need

Comment: yes, i checked it. but only 2 manual link was in demos. (Manual Call to get an ajax content, Manual Call calling through an other link) And they was work only with links (`href`), i haven't a `href` in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

the fallowing code is for showing the div...

```
$('#button').click(function(){

      $('#mydiv').show();
});
```

if you want to show it in modal then you have to place this div in modal......

Comment: its  the jquery basic way. but i want to show it with nyroModal.

Answer (score 0):

Other than simulating a click event from a hidden link i think this is the only way. You need to pass the data through using $.nmData(data, options) function.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $.nmData($('#mydiv').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to show a simple popup , Please check the below snippet,

```js
$(function(){
 var $button = $('#button');
 $button.on('click', function(){
  $('#modal_box').css('display','block');
 });
 $('.close').on('click', function(){
  $('#modal_box').css('display','none');
 });
});
```

```css
#modal_box {
 width:50%;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:300px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 right:;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:25%;
 display:none;
 background:#CCC;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal_box"> <a href="#" class="close">Close</a></div>
<div id="button"> Click here </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```